# Combining two separate JSON data objects into one in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdata, nsmutabledata

Im trying to get 2 separate JSON data objects containing 2 twitter users feeds but am having lots of trouble. I want to process them both at the same time and put them into a table but am having difficulties.

I have a global NSMutableData that gets each of the JSON requests appended to it. Once all of it is in one place im trying to then update the table with the global NSMutableData. allTheData is the global NSMutable object.

```
if ([twitterAccounts count] > 0) {
    while (accountsize != [twitterAccounts count]) {
      [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

           [allTheData appendData:responseData];
      }];
      accountsize = accountsize + 1;
   }}

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:allTheData waitUntilDone:YES];
   });

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
  self.tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
  [self.TwitterTableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
   NSDictionary *tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.textLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];


   return cell;
}
```

Whenever I run this code it crashes and spits out the following

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x2622012 0x131ae7e 0x2621deb 0xe4f817 0x568c 0x132e6b0 0xd5b035 0x25a5f3f 0x25a596f 0x25c8734 0x25c7f44 0x25c7e1b 0x290d7e3 0x290d668 0x26265c 0x258d 0x24b5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation regarding `performRequestWithHandler`:

> Performs an asynchronous request and calls the specified handler when done.

This means that your request handler will only be called once and that there's no need for the appending of the chunks. It's very possible that you're crashing because the code isn't executed in the order you expect. I would try moving the call to `receiveData` into the handler block so that it gets executed only when you actually have the data:

```
            [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,^{
                       [self receiveData:responseData];
                });

            }];
            accountsize = accountsize + 1;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please add the code for "receiveData", also if your snippet is enclosed within another block, add the relevant code. Or at least explain what the "}}" on line #5 closes.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:allTheData waitUntilDone:YES];
   });
```

You are calling a method on the main thread, why perform dispatch_async then? **you should only wrap the call to `reloadData` in `dispatch_async` on the main queue.** 
As well, I would call `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` for each tweet, and then add them to the array. 
I think that appending raw data bytes might be corrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse each json object and append them to an NSMutableArray. Concatenating NSMutableData objects with unparsed json seems incredibly backwards.